# Vuforia - Model drawn over target has wrong size

Tags: java, android, vuforia

I have replaced the teapot with a rectangle using [this tutorial](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot) and also changed the target image by uploading a new image to [vuforia target manager](https://developer.vuforia.com/target-manager) and replacing the dataset files with the new ones. The size of the image is : 1419x972. Also 1419 was the width I entered when asked in target manager. So in the model .xml file I can see the correct size of the image.

In rectangle model I have entered these sizes:

```
double w = 394;
double h = 120;
double[] BTN_VERTS = {-0.5*w, -0.5*h, 0.0, 0.5*w, -0.5*h, 0.0, 0.5*w, 0.5*h, 0.0, -0.5*w, 0.5*h, 0.0};
```

So it should draw a rectangle on the target with a width around one third of the target. But what I see is a rectangle with a width almost the same as the target. Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem. I divided all sizes by 3 and everything now fits perfectly. Can anyone tell me why it might have happened and if it's the same for all targets or there might be cases that this 3 doesn't apply any more?
I don't have any other multiplications by 3 or things like that in my code so I assume it's probably related to vuforia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your problem is not related to Vuforia. I don't have your code for the renderer but since you say you are working with the teapot example I am pretty sure that this is your problem:

In the `ImageTargetRenderer` class have a look at these lines

```
Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                    OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT);
Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT,
                    OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT, OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT);
```

and find out the the value of `OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT`. In the teapot example it was set like this

```
private static final float OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT = 3.0f;
```

What this essentially does is translating you matrix by `3.0` in the z plane and scaling all three dimensions (x, y and z) by `3.0` as well. In your case, the scaling part is important.

That is, if you don't want this scaling to happen then simply change `OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT` to some other value e.g. `1.0` (no scaling). This should solve your problem.

However, please note that `OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT` was also used for translating the matrix. So make sure that you adjust the value in `Matrix.translateM(...)`

And since you are now working with matrixes I suggest that you take a look at the [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html) class in the Android documentation.

Comment: WOW!! I can't believe I had missed that. I had the same problem with translation as well. So you fixed all my problems. Thanks.